# How to Implement Vectorized Backprop in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, machine-learning-model

I'm working on a school project and am stuck on how to implement backpropagation in Numpy with the current forward prop structure I have. The aim of this script is to make a simple dynamic (meaning any number of layers and nodes) fully connected network using only numpy.

I think that I have to find the derivatives of the activation functions and multipliy it by the original error as well as the derivative of each activation function I encounter moving backward.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement this correctly in my script.

It'd be a great help if someone could explain in English what exactly I have to do given the complexities of the setup here, or even give a recommendation for a video/post that deals w dynamic size backprop.

Right now all the weights and biases are being stored in lists for future backprop, and I'm able to get the error for each output with the small amount of code currently in the backprop function.

This code block

```
#initialize a test model w/ 128 bacth and lr of 0.01
model = Model(128, 0.01)

#simple x data input
X = np.array([[1,1],[0,0],[12,5]])
Y = np.array([[1],[0],[-1]])
#adding 4 layers
z = model.add(X, 3, "sigmoid")
z = model.add(z, 1, "sigmoid", output=True)

#this is a full forward pass through the layers
z = model.predict(X)
print(z)

#this is the error of the predictions
print(model.backprop(z, Y))
```

Outputs the following vectors:

```
[[0.50006457]
 [0.50006459]
 [0.50006431]]

[[0.24993544]
 [0.2500646 ]
 [2.25019293]]
```

Like I said, not sure how to move forward ( or backward ;) ) from here.

Below is the full script needed to run the example:

```
import math
import numpy as np

#everything below is defining activation functions
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def b_relu(input):
  return max((0, max(input)))

def bd_relu(input):
  if(input < 0 or input == 0):
    return 0
  else:
    return 1

def b_sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

def bd_sigmoid(input):
  return sigmoid(input) * (1 - sigmoid(input))

def b_tanh(input):
  top = (math.exp(input) - math.exp(-input))
  bottom = (math.exp(input) + math.exp(-input))
  return (top/bottom)

#helper functions for tanh
def cosh(input):
  return ((math.exp(input) + math.exp(-input)) / 2)
def sinh(input):
  return ((math.exp(input) - math.exp(-input)) / 2) 

def bd_tanh(input):
  top = (math.pow(cosh(input), 2) - math.pow(sinh(input), 2))
  bottom = math.pow(input, 2)
  return (top / bottom)

def b_softmax(z):
  # subracting the max adds numerical stability
  shiftx = z - np.max(z,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
  exps = np.exp(shiftx)
  return exps / np.sum(exps,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]

def bd_softmax(Y_hat, Y):
  return Y_hat - Y

def b_linear(input):
  return input
def bd_linear(input):
  return 1

#vectorizing the activation and deriv. activation functions
relu = np.vectorize(b_relu)
d_relu = np.vectorize(bd_relu)

sigmoid = np.vectorize(b_sigmoid)
d_sigmoid = np.vectorize(bd_sigmoid)

tanh = np.vectorize(b_tanh)
d_tanh = np.vectorize(bd_tanh)

softmax = np.vectorize(b_softmax)
d_softmax = np.vectorize(bd_softmax)

linear = np.vectorize(b_linear)
d_linear = np.vectorize(bd_linear)

class Model:
  def __init__(self, batch, lr):
    #initializing self lists to keep track of stuff for bacthes, forward prop & backporp
    self.batch = batch
    self.lr = lr
    self.W = []
    self.B = []
    self.A = []
    self.Z = []
    self.X = []
    self.layers = []
    self.tempW = []
    self.tempB = []

    #store error for backprop
    self.output_error = []

  #initialize the weights during 'model.add' so we can test our network shapes dynamically w/out model.compile
  #added an output bool here so we can make sure the shape of the output network is (1,n)
  def initial_weights(self, input_data, output_shape, output=False):
    B = np.zeros((1, output_shape))
    #assigning the shape 
    W = np.random.uniform(-1e-3, 1e-3, size = (input_data.shape[len(input_data.shape) - 1], output_shape))
    self.B.append(B)
    self.W.append(W)

  def add(self, input_data, output_shape, activation, output=False):
    #append to layers so we have a correct index value
    self.layers.append(69)

    #making sure our data in a numpy array
    if (type(input_data) == np.ndarray):
      X = input_data
    else:
      X = np.asarray(input_data)

    #adding data and activations to self lists
    self.X.append(X)
    self.A.append(activation)


    #keep track of our index & initializing random weights for dynamic comatibility testing
    index = len(self.layers)-1
    self.initial_weights(input_data, output_shape, output=False)

    X2 = self.forward(input_data, index)
    #printing layer info 
    print("Layer:", index)
    print("Input Shape: ", X.shape)
    print("Weight Shape: ", self.W[index].shape)
    print("Output Shape: ", X2.shape)
    print(" ")
    return(X2)

  def forward(self, input_data, index):
    #pulling weights and biases from  main lists for operations
    B = self.B[index]
    W = self.W[index]

    #matmul of data # weights + bias
    Z = np.matmul(input_data, W) + B
    #summing each row of inputs to activation node
    for x in Z:
      x = sum(x)
    #pulling activation from index 
    act = str(self.A[index])
    #activating 
    Z = activate(Z, act)
    #keeping track of Z i guess
    self.Zappend = Z
    return(Z)

  def predict(self, input_data):
    for x in range(len(self.layers)):
      z = model.forward(input_data, x)
      input_data = z
    return z

  def backprop(self, model_output, ground_truth):
    #------------------------------
    #now begins the backprop portion
    #let's start with finding the error between predictions and actual values

    #gonna do MSE to keep it simple
    self.output_error = (ground_truth - model_output) ** 2
    #so now we have the error of the output layer, this tells us two things, how wrong we were, and in which direction we should update
    #the outputs of these nodes

    '''
    What to do if this was linear regression (for m & b)
    1. Take the error and multiply it by the transpose of the last layer weights 
    (I think the error in this case is where the prime activation function should be if we had activations)
    2. The last layer bias is just the error
    3. The second to last layer inputs is the bias times the transpose of second layers weights
    3. Then I have no idea
    '''
    return self.output_error
```